# Linear transformation V -> W can be represented by M(k,n)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For any 2 vector spaces V and W, a linear transformation T:V->W can be represented by A (Which is an element of M(k,n) )

M(k,n) is all matrices with k rows and n columns.

In my book, it states "This is false and is only true if both vector spaces are finite dimensional."  Could someone please interpret this for me?

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, by choosing a basis in $V$ and in $W$ you can represent elements of $V$ or $W$ by tuples $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$, where $n$ is the dimension of the vector space in question. Then a matrix represents a linear transformation, which is given by multiplying vectors (tuples) with that matrix.

If $V$ or $W$ is not finite dimensional, then this makes no sense. You cannot multiply an "infinite tuple" and a matrix.